# Function keys not work or have delay

Tags: drivers, kernel, brightness, backlight, function-keys

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 and all my function keys are not working or have 2min delay except volume keys. Also, I am using Thinkpad 11e. 
I checked online and it looks like a kernel problem.
Here is more information: 
1: My current kernel boot line (`cat /proc/cmdline`):

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=dd0e072b-5b7c-4f42-96d0-df430d64a627 ro quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor vt.handoff=7
```

2: Information about my video card (`lspci -k | grep -iA2 VGA`):

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)    Subsystem: Lenovo Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

3:Information about my known backlight interfaces (`for interface in /sys/class/backlight/*; do echo -e "\n $interface"; cat $interface/{brightness,max_brightness,actual_brightness}; done`):

```
 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
5454
5454
5454

 /sys/class/backlight/thinkpad_screen
7
7
7
```

4: A listing of my loaded kernel modules (lsmod):

```
> Module                  Size  Used by ccm                    20480  0
> rfcomm                 77824  2 bnep                   20480  2
> snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45056  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
> snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek intel_rapl    
> 20480  0 intel_powerclamp       16384  0 coretemp               16384 
> 0 arc4                   16384  2 kvm                   598016  0
> irqbypass              16384  1 kvm punit_atom_debug       16384  0
> crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 crc32_pclmul           16384  0
> ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
> aesni_intel           167936  0 iwlmvm                360448  0
> aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel lrw                   
> 16384  1 aesni_intel glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
> ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel cryptd                
> 24576  3 ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel mac80211         
> 757760  1 iwlmvm intel_cstate           16384  0 input_leds           
> 16384  0 iwlwifi               229376  1 iwlmvm joydev                
> 20480  0 serio_raw              16384  0 cfg80211              581632 
> 3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211 snd_soc_rt5670        126976  0 nxp_nci_i2c 
> 16384  0 nxp_nci                16384  1 nxp_nci_i2c snd_soc_rl6231   
> 16384  1 snd_soc_rt5670 nci                    69632  2
> nxp_nci,nxp_nci_i2c nfc                   110592  2 nxp_nci,nci
> lpc_ich                24576  0 uvcvideo               90112  0
> videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo videobuf2_memops       16384 
> 1 videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
> videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hda_intel 
> 36864  3 videodev              180224  3
> uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hda_codec         135168  4
> snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
> media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev snd_hda_core        
> 86016  5
> snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
> shpchp                 36864  0 mei_txe                20480  0
> snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec btusb                 
> 45056  0 mei                   102400  1 mei_txe btrtl                
> 16384  1 btusb snd_intel_sst_acpi     16384  0 snd_intel_sst_core    
> 77824  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform    90112  1
> snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
> snd_soc_core          233472  2
> snd_soc_rt5670,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_compress           20480 
> 1 snd_soc_core ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
> snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core snd_pcm              
> 110592  8
> snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_rt5670,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_soc_core
> snd_seq_midi           16384  0 snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1
> snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
> thinkpad_acpi          94208  1 nvram                  16384  1
> thinkpad_acpi snd_seq                69632  2
> snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi tpm_infineon           20480  0
> snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
> hci_uart               94208  0 snd_timer              32768  2
> snd_seq,snd_pcm btbcm                  16384  2 hci_uart,btusb btqca  
> 16384  1 hci_uart dw_dmac                16384  0 btintel             
> 16384  2 hci_uart,btusb dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac snd   
> 86016  21
> snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
> bluetooth             552960  33
> btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb rfkill_gpio      
> 16384  0 i2c_designware_platform    16384  0 i2c_designware_core   
> 20480  1 i2c_designware_platform pwm_lpss_platform      16384  0
> soundcore              16384  1 snd pwm_lpss               16384  1
> pwm_lpss_platform spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0 8250_dw             
> 16384  0 soc_button_array       16384  0 mac_hid                16384 
> 0 parport_pc             32768  0 ppdev                  20480  0 lp  
> 20480  0 parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev ip_tables
> 28672  0 x_tables               36864  1 ip_tables autofs4            
> 40960  2 i915                 1314816  5 i2c_algo_bit           16384 
> 1 i915 drm_kms_helper        167936  1 i915 syscopyarea           
> 16384  1 drm_kms_helper sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
> sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper r8169                 
> 81920  0 fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper psmouse       
> 131072  0 ahci                   36864  3 drm                   368640
> 6 i915,drm_kms_helper libahci                32768  1 ahci mii        
> 16384  1 r8169 wmi                    16384  0 video                 
> 40960  2 thinkpad_acpi,i915 i2c_hid                20480  0 dwc3      
> 102400  0 hid                   118784  1 i2c_hid udc_core            
> 53248  1 dwc3 sdhci_acpi             16384  0 ulpi                  
> 16384  1 dwc3 fjes                   28672  0 sdhci                 
> 45056  1 sdhci_acpi pinctrl_cherryview     32768  0
```

5: My /var/log/Xorg.0.log file:

```
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23443256/
```

I have tried to enforce my laptop to use my intel backlight setting (`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`) and it still not work:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "card0"
    Driver     "intel"
    Option     "Backlight" "Intel_backlight"
    BusID      "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Comment: The thinkpad_acpi driver should automatically select an appropriate mask for your machine. But on a rare occasions you might need to change the hotkey mask for key events to happen. In that case, read the recommended hotkey_mask from hotkey_recommended_mask, set the extra bits you need, and write the result to hotkey_mask. These files (actually, "sysfs attributes") can be found on sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi See [this](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_get_special_keys_to_work#thinkpad_acpi_events)

Comment: How can I set those extra bits? can you give me an example or some hints? I can't really understand the method on Thinkpad Wiki.